# Фраза в скобках в начале предложения. Что говорят правила?

Tags: пунктуация, вставка

[*Как-то раз Джулия сказала, что идеальный партнер — человек, которого можно спрятать в шкаф и доставать по необходимости.]

...

В сердце больше не осталось места. **(Крайне тесное)** пространство, отведенное женщине в шкафу Джексонова сердца, почти целиком занимала свечка, что горела чувствами к его шотландской немезиде...*
[**К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоем**](http://knijky.ru/books/chut-svet-s-sobakoyu-vdvoem?page=37)

Мне такое предложение (со скобками в его начале) попалось впервые.
Верна ли пунктуация? Можно ***так*** "строить" предложение?
Какими правилами руководствовался переводчик?

Comment: Переводчик мог просто воспроизвести без изменений авторское взятие в скобки (того, что можно прочесть для большей ясности, а  можно и пропустить; украшает ли это стиль повествования - вопрос отдельный, но ошибки я не вижу). Меня больше смущает смысл выражения "_свечка горела чувствами_" - здесь можно именно к переводчику вопрос задать (если, конечно, в оригинале не было такого странного смысла и на самом деле она эти чувства воспламеняет, подобно свече в системе зажигания и т. п.), .

Comment: Это развёрнутая метафора. У кого-то любовь - костёр, а у него слабо мигающая свечка, но  горит она чувствами к другой женщине - " шотландской немезиде, старшему детективу-инспектору Луизе Монро. Давнее пламя вяло мигало, никогда не разгоралось в безвоздушности их разлуки.., они не виделись два года, она замужем за другим и родила от него ребенка. У людей это не считается отношениями. Кто-то должен свечку погасить." А для другой женщины пока "нет места в шкафу его сердца".

Answer (score 1):

Отвечала на вопрос о пунктуации в предложениях со вставками и обнаружила следующее:

*Наиболее сильным выделяющим знаком препинания являются скобки: они выделяют вставную конструкцию внутри предложения или в конце его (**в начале предложения вставка, будучи дополнительным сообщением, не употребляется**)...*
[**Знаки препинания при вставках. § 97**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128)

Получается, что скобки в предложении, указанном в вопросе, поставлены не по правилам.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это не пунктуация. Может быть, слово "пространство" недостаточно передаёт смысл переведённого слова,пришлось его дополнить дополнительными сведениями,вот он и взял их в скобки, чтобы показать, что это необязательные сведения, что это можно перевести и по-другому.