# Понятен ли переход от заголовка к пояснению в скобках?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На ошибки орф. и пункт. прошу не обращать внимания; интересует только переход от заголовка к тексту: вменяемо ли пояснение в скобках?

> **Откровение Иоанна или Апокалипсис**
>
> (в переводе с греческого – Откровение) святого Иоанна Богослова – это
>   «единственная пророческая книга Нового Завета. Она предсказывает о
>   грядущих судьбах человечества, о конце мира и о начале вечной жизни, и
>   поэтому, естественно, помещается в конце Священного Писания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пояснение в скобках, конечно, понятно, но оформлять ТАК начало текста (и предложения) нельзя.
Недавно я задавала похожий вопрос: [**Фраза в скобках в начале предложения. Что говорят правила?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436163/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) Получилось так, что через некоторое время сама нашла ответ в тексте правил:

*Наиболее сильным выделяющим знаком препинания являются скобки: они выделяют вставную конструкцию внутри предложения или в конце его (**в начале предложения вставка, будучи дополнительным сообщением, не употребляется**)...*

Поэтому, думаю, текст все-таки придется начинать таким образом:

**Апокалипсис (в переводе с греческого – раскрытие, откровение; снятие покрова) святого Иоанна Богослова — это...**

Answer (score 2):

**Откровение Иоанна, или Апокалипсис**

**Апокалипсис** (в переводе с греческого — Откровение) св. Иоанна Богослова — это единственная пророческая книга Нового Завета.

http://bookitut.ru/Svyashhennoe-pisanie-Novogo-Zaveta.93.html

Апока́липсис — в христианстве текст-откровение. Также вместе со словом «армагеддон» употребляется в значении конца света или катастрофы планетарного масштаба.